# Xamarin Image tap gestures are not always recognised

Tags: performance, user-interface, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, gesture-recognition

so we are developing an app on cross-platform Xamarin. We are now testing it on Android on a few real devices, and we noticed that wherever we have an image with a Tap Gesture Recognizer the tap does not always work.

We tried increasing the section by increasing the image's size and decreasing the used part of the images, but we still have this issue. Its like some times it just doesn't work, even if you did tap on the image.

How can we fix this?

**Edit**

We updated to the last pre-release of Xamarin.Forms (2.5.0.121934) and it seems to be fixed. We are going to continue running tests to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We updated to the last pre-release of Xamarin.Forms (2.5.0.121934) and it seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Put a hotspot over it or behind it setting image's input to transparent. Hotspot can be whatever works best for you, transparent boxview, contentview etc. It's sometimes better to use hotspots as you can allow users to tap a bit around the image etc.